# TFS2010 web deploy with multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, msdeploy

I have an MVC3 solution (.sln) that I want to build with TFS and that solution has multiple projects. For the deployment of the website (the aim of this exercise) I do not need all the other projects. The website is basically set up to be dependent on the domain project so it does build before the website. There is an API project in there that is not part of what need to be deployed for this build script.

How do I get TFS to deploy this correctly, I really do not care if it builds the API project but I would like to only deploy the web project? I can type the msdeploy command on the command prompt on the build server to deploy the site.

TFS does the build successfully, I can see it in the drop folder (all projects) but then it continues to only deploy the API project to my website. That is not what I want, I want it to deploy the site build (not the API build) to that site. I do not have a domain so the server is in a workgroup and these are my build parameters:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
/p:MSDeployServiceUrl=http://IPofMyServer/msdeployagentservice
/p:DeployIisAppPath="MVC - Jack"
/p:UserName=APPServer\Administrator
/p:Password=xxxxxx
/p:Configuration=Release
```

Thank you Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically opted to create a new solution with the domain project, web project that depends on the domain, unit test project and integration tests project.